# Why is styles.content.getRight not working?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to create a simple typo3 template. The template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>T3 TEST BLAH</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### -->
<h1>Webpage</h1>

    <div id="right">
        <h2>RIGHT:</h2>
        <!-- ###CONTENT_SIDEBAR### -->
        <!-- ###CONTENT_SIDEBAR### -->
    </div>


    <div id="content">
        <!-- ###CONTENT### -->
        <!-- ###CONTENT### -->
    </div>

    <!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### -->
</body>
</html>
```

and my typoscript like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10{
template = FILE
template.file = fileadmin/template.html
   workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY
  subparts{
    CONTENT_SIDEBAR < styles.content.getRight
    CONTENT < styles.content.get
  }
}
```

all I get is the content from styles.content.get but not styles.content.getRight  (or getLeft). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few things you could try:

First of all, make sure there is content in the "right" column.

Then you could try whether it works if you use

```
CONTENT_SIDEBAR < styles.content.get
```

to see if the subpart gets recognized.

Another problem I have seen is that you need some content between the subpart markers (don't know if that was fixed yet) - so try writing

```
<!-- ###CONTENT_SIDEBAR### --> 
test
<!-- ###CONTENT_SIDEBAR### -->
```

HTH,

Susanne

Comment: oh, I found the problem... my fault: I edited the wrong page lol. ;) I edited the root page (which is a shortcut to the start page) instead of the start page. Now it works -.-

Answer (score 1):

`styles.content.getRight` has been removed with `fluid_styled_content`:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/Installation/Upgrading/

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have subpart `"CONTENT_SIDEBAR"`, try use `"RIGHT"` like your subpart id.

Comment: I thought the subparts were controlled by the comments(?) but I also changed it to RIGHT and it doesn't work... it is just empty.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong, `CONTENT_SIDEBAR` is a valid subpart in @blackhatmario's template.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is valid and subparts are valid as well it's `CONTENT_SIDEBAR` **NOT** `RIGHT`.

Make sure you included correct `CSS Styled Content (css_styled_content)` in your TypoScript template and you cleared the cache.

Make sure you have some dummy code (whatever) between the subpart's comments like:

```
<!-- ###CONTENT_SIDEBAR### start--> Foo <!-- ###CONTENT_SIDEBAR### end-->
```

If you haven't and don't want to insert anything there, better use **marker** instead of **subpart**, like:

```
<body>
<!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### -->
    <h1>Webpage</h1>

    <div id="right">
        <h2>RIGHT:</h2>
         ###CONTENT_SIDEBAR###
    </div>


    <div id="content">
        ###CONTENT###
    </div>
<!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### -->
</body>
```

and TS:

```
page >
page = PAGE
page {
  10 = TEMPLATE
  10 {
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/template.html
    workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY
    marks {
      CONTENT < styles.content.get
      CONTENT_SIDEBAR < styles.content.getRight
    }
  }
}
```

Finally use TypoScript analyzer to check if some extension or additional TS doesn't override `CONTENT_SIDEBAR` and/or `styles.content.getRight`.

Last advice maybe weird, but make sure that you put the content element in valid column and it isn't hidden or disabled.